# Find stones, OpenCV

Tags: opencv

I have such images. How do I find the stones on them use OpenCV?
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

There will be some methods you can use to find the stones in the picture. Finding all the stones perfectly will be a very difficult thing to do however. The task you have been given is more of a thinking exercise (in my opinion) which will not have a perfect solution.

A very simple method would be to use `GaussianBlur` (simply a blur) on the images, to remove most of the bumps in the rocks, then find the rock outlines which you can do using the `Canny` and `findContours` functions which should find outlines around most of the rocks. The last step is actually identifying a rock which I shall leave to you (i.e. what characterises a rock in terms of an outline).

You may find [this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html) tutorial useful.